Who was the first philosopher to describe approximation?
Who was the first philosopher to describe what we now call curve fitting or approximation?
Pierre Duhem discusses this a bit in Aim & Structure of Physical Theory, pt. 2, ch. 3 "Mathematical Deduction & Physical Theory", pp. 132-43, § 4 of which is the "Mathematics of Approximation":

a mathematical deduction is of no use to the physicist so long as it is limited to asserting that a given rigorously true proposition has for its consequence the rigorous accuracy of some such other proposition. To be useful to the physicist, it must still be proved that the second proposition remains approximately exact when the first is only approximately true.

What does it mean to be "approximately true"? Isn't something either true or false?

this “mathematics of approximation” is not a simpler and cruder form of mathematics. On the contrary, it is a more thorough and more refined form of mathematics, requiring the solution of problems at times enormously difficult, sometimes even transcending the methods at the disposal of algebra today.

This describes what machine learning (=sophisticated curve-fitting) is.
Certainly philosophers before Duhem (✝1916) have discussed this, but who was the first?
Cf. "Duhem's Bull"
See my related question: "Are mathematical suppositions of physical theories determined uniquely according to Aristotle and Plato?"
another very related question: "If nature is inherently imprecise, how is it so easy for us to conceptualize mathematical certainties?"

Approximate truth is a popular notion among realists, see SEP. It is not restricted to curve-fitting and the like and occurs already in Boole's Laws of Thought (1854):"Grant that the procedure thus established can only conduct us to probable or to approximate results; it only follows, that the larger number of the generalizations of physical science possess but a probable or approximate truth." He was not the first either.

Newton in The Method of Fluxions (1671, published 1736) already writes "as in common Arithmetick we approximate continually to the truth, by admitting Decimal Parts in infinitum..."

Mathematics is not true, it is useful. As such, there are simply more useful and less useful formulations. Get used to it :-) Alternative truths is another matter, not useful at all.

@ScottRowe If the math and reality correspond, that's truth. There are physically useful and physically useless mathematical deductions (cf. §§ 2 & 3 of Aim & Structure pp. 135-8).

Certainly, with non-Euclidean geometry etc., it might not be able to be said that that sort of math "is concerned with matter in which perfect certitude is found" (In I Eth. l. 3 n. 36); cf. Kline's provocatively titled book Mathematics, The Loss of Certainty.

What is your criterion for how close it needs to correspond? To me, building something that works is a test, but we keep building better things. So truth isn't really a thing, but "I got it to work" is. Then, "I got it to work better" is a further thing.

Analogy might have something to do with approximation. Duhem's example (ibid. p. 134): "to say in a proposition of theoretical fact that a certain line has a length of 1 centimeter, or 0.999 cm., or 0.993 cm., or 1.002 cm., or 1.003 cm. is to formulate propositions which are for the mathematician essentially different; but we change nothing of the practical fact translated by the theoretical fact if our means of measurement do not allow us to evaluate lengths of less than 0.001 cm." ∴ those measurements are analogous, practically.

Commenting on Aristotle, Metaphysics Chapter 3: 995a10, in the context of "The Method to Be Followed in the Search for Truth", St. Thomas Aquinas says:


He [Aristotle] shows that the method which is absolutely the best should not be demanded in all the sciences. He says that the “exactness” [acribologia], i.e., the careful and certain demonstrations, found in mathematics should not be demanded in the case of all things of which we have science, but only in the case of those things which have no matter; for things that have matter are subject to motion and change, and therefore in their case complete certitude cannot be had. For in the case of these things we do not look for what exists always and of necessity, but only for what exists in the majority of cases [ut in pluribus].


Thus, probability/statistics is required for studying changing things.

Computing systems have no matter, but expecting perfection of them is apparently a forlorn hope. Also, as best I know, curve fitting is used in cryptography. It is the basis for a known secret that is hard for someone else to discover. Anti-knowledge?

@ScottRowe "Computing systems have no matter" Sure they do. All information has a material substrate.

So mathematics is information and has matter. What is something that has no matter? We would have no information about it. What would we talk about then?

@ScottRowe "What is something that has no matter?" Being qua being, what metaphysics studies (the 3rd of the 3 degrees of abstraction; cf. end of this answer for details).

But then it has no information, as you said, so we can never know about it. Your contention.

@ScottRowe Information ≠ knowledge, just as sensory data ≠ knowledge; it's merely a means whereby we acquire knowledge. Actually, something is more intelligible the less bound to matter is it ("for things that have matter are subject to motion and change" and thus not stable/immutable like universal truths). Cf. theses 18-20.

How do we acquire knowledge without information?

@ScottRowe Information certainly helps us know. Information and sensory data are the means whereby (quo) we know, not what (quod) we know (cf. the fallacy of conflating quo/quod).

How would we know what we know without a means to know whereby we know it? Where does the initial knowing come from, and how is it different from any other unverifiable thought?

@ScottRowe "Where does the initial knowing come from?" What Aristotle calls νοῦς: "Intelligence [intellectus, νοῦς] deals with the principles [ἀρχὰς] of intelligibles and of beings. For science [scientia, ἐπιστήμη] deals with beings that have proof [ἀποδείξεως], but the principles are without proof [ἀναπόδεικτοι], so that science would not deal with principles; rather intelligence would." —Magna Moralia, I, c. 34, 1197ª20-23.

@ScottRowe Cf. the notion of ens primum cognitum ("being [is what is] first known").

I'm looking at the Quo/Quotd paper. What it says on the first page - that originally external things in the world were regarded as certain and knowable but things in the mind don't have the same standing, but now external things are regarded as 'unknowable' and we can only be certain of the contents of the mind - stunning! A recipe for madness! If you are basing your Argument on Aristotle, be aware that he didn't think the mind was truly reliable, but only a tool for assessing external things. More or less the opposite of what you are saying? Cheers!

@ScottRowe I'm reminded of this article, which dispels the myth that beings of reason (ens rationis) are somehow not real.
